# vsftp upload to permission 777 by default

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, vsftpd

When I upload something using FTP on my ubuntu server with VSFTP it is defaulting to permission 600, how can I make it go to 777?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just uncomment the `local_umask` line in your /etc/vsftpd.conf and edit the value to `000`:

```
local_umask=000
```

then restart vsftpd:

```
systemctl restart vsftpd
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked!

Comment: If you find my answer useful you might decide to upvote and accept it.

Comment: Have done, I had to wait 5 minutes you see

Comment: Welcome on ServerFault!

Comment: I had also to use `anon_upload_enable=YES` `anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES` `anon_other_write_enable=YES` for it fully to work. You may also need to relax some other restrictions to have complete 777.

Answer (score -1):

local_umask=000

file_open_mode=0777

Above two lines to be enabled or placed in vsftpd.conf file. So that files which we are moving using FTP to server will have -rwxrwxrwx permission for user, group and others.

Finally restart vsftpd service.

Thanks for the above answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/531236)